# I am using UIColour for colour line but its not give me properly result ... so i want know how to fix it

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5, uicolor

here , this is my code , When i am click on `colorChange` the it should be give for color choosen . After the colour choosen the selected colour must be display but it wont gave which colour i choose it given some other colour

```
let kActionSheetColor: Int = 100

func actionSheet(_ actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAt buttonIndex: Int) {
    
    //var colorsArray: [UIColor] = [#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.1491314173, blue: 0, alpha: 1),  #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.7568627596, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.2745098174, green: 0.4862745106, blue: 0.1411764771, alpha: 1)]
    let myblackColor = UIColor.black
    let myRedColor = UIColor.red
    let myblueColor = UIColor.blue
    let mygreenColor = UIColor.green
    
    
    if actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex != buttonIndex {
        if actionSheet.tag == kActionSheetColor {

            colorButton.title = actionSheet.buttonTitle(at: buttonIndex)
            switch buttonIndex {
            case 0:
                //drawingView.lineColor = UIColor.black
//                    drawingView.lineColor = colorsArray[2]
//                    print("black \(colorsArray[2])")
                drawingView.lineColor = UIColor.gray
                
            case 1:
                //drawingView.lineColor = UIColor.systemRed
                //drawingView.lineColor = colorsArray[0]
                drawingView.lineColor = myRedColor
                
            case 2:
                //drawingView.lineColor = UIColor.systemGreen
                //drawingView.lineColor = colorsArray[3]
                drawingView.lineColor = myblueColor
            case 3:
                //drawingView.lineColor = UIColor.systemBlue
               // drawingView.lineColor = colorsArray[2]
                drawingView.lineColor = mygreenColor
            default:
                break
            }
        } else {

            toolButton.title = actionSheet.buttonTitle(at: buttonIndex)
            drawingView.drawTool = ACEDrawingToolTypePen
//                switch buttonIndex {
//                case 0:
//                    drawingView.drawTool = ACEDrawingToolTypePen
//                default:
//                    break
//                }

//                // if eraser, disable color and alpha selection
//                alphaButton.isEnabled = buttonIndex != 6
//               colorButton.isEnabled = alphaButton.isEnabled

            colorButton.isEnabled
            
        }
    }
}


@IBAction func colorChange(_ sender: Any) {
    let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Selet a color", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: "", otherButtonTitles:  "Black", "Red", "Green", "Blue")
    actionSheet.tag = kActionSheetColor
    actionSheet.show(in: view)
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong buttonIndex in your switch. The black button is at index 2. Button with index 0 is the Destructive button